# xpra: failed to receive anything, not an xpra server?

Tags: ubuntu, xpra

I am experimenting with `xpra`. On `calculon` computer (expecting it will be server) I ran

```
$ xpra start :100 --start=xterm
Entering daemon mode; any further errors will be reported to:
  /run/user/1000/xpra/:100.log
```

log is apparently ok. The on `pterosuar` computer, which is expected to be a  client, I ran

```
$ xpra attach ssh/dims@calculon/100
2018-10-23 22:04:18,015 cannot use pycups for printing: No module named cups
2018-10-23 22:04:18,120 xpra gtk2 client version 0.15.8 (r11211)
2018-10-23 22:04:18,352 PyOpenGL warning: missing accelerate module
2018-10-23 22:04:18,352 PyOpenGL warning: missing array format handlers: numeric, vbo, vbooffset
2018-10-23 22:04:18,352 OpenGL Version: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 384.130
2018-10-23 22:04:18,355 OpenGL enabled with GeForce GT 650M/PCIe/SSE2
2018-10-23 22:04:18,484 detected keyboard: rules=evdev, model=pc105, layout=us
2018-10-23 22:04:18,486 desktop size is 1920x1080 with 1 screen(s):
2018-10-23 22:04:18,486   ':0.0' (508x286 mm - DPI: 96x95) workarea: 1920x993 at 0x24
2018-10-23 22:04:18,486     monitor 1 (382x215 mm - DPI: 127x127)
bash: /home/dims/.xpra/run-xpra: No such file or directory
2018-10-23 22:04:18,970 failed to receive anything, not an xpra server?
2018-10-23 22:04:18,970   could also be the wrong username, password or port
2018-10-23 22:04:18,970   or maybe this server does not support 'unknown' compression or 'bencode' packet encoding?
2018-10-23 22:04:18,971 Connection lost
```

Why is it writing something about `Nvidia`? Shouldn't it be in-memory screen?

Both computers are running Ubuntu-16, I can `ssh` from `pterosaur` to `calculon` and can do normal remote X11 and/or VNC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was because of old version of `xpra` on client. I [followed winswitch site instructions](http://winswitch.org/downloads/debian-repository.html) on "server" machine, but just installed from pure apt on "client". Once I did the same on client, it started to work.